# How to cherry pick 2 out of 5 commits of a pull request on GitHub?

Tags: github, commit, pull-request, git-cherry-pick

I'm new to GitHub. Someone submitted a pull request with 5 commits. 3 of them have a little bug, though, so must wait. How can pick 2 of them for my project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to leave a comment asking for the contributor to submit again his/her pull request with only the 2 commits, in order for you to apply said PR (pull request) without having to do any work.

The other solution, from the page "[Merging Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request)", is to **merge locally**, on your local clone, in a dedicated branch.
You can then cherry-pick the right commits you want, and push those back to your repo, but make sure to leave a comment in the discussion section of the pull request explaining that

- you only took 2 of the 5 commits into account,
- the contributor should rebase his work on top of your new updated master (which now includes said 2 commits), and re-submit the same pull request with the last (and hopefully fixed) 3 commits.

This is similar to the first option, except you don't have to wait for the fixes: you can grab what you want locally, test and push.

Comment: From the OP's description it sounds like the commits are unrelated, otherwise he wouldn't be able to cherry-pick among them anyways. In that case, these should be split into separe pull requests in the first place, so I'd go with your first option to leave a comment requesting the contributor to 1) split the pull requests and resubmit 2) fix the bugs before re-submitting.

Comment: @MichaelWild I agree, but why wait? Why not grab everything and sort locally?

Comment: True. If it's not much work, and only a matter of `git add remote ...`, `git fetch ...`, `git cherry-pick ...` (possibly using `-x` to indicate the origin of the patch), why not.